# creating a subquery of all the users in a table which has their id in the other tabel

Tags: c#, sql

I have 2 tables: table1 and table 2. this table have different fields however the field 'uid' at table1 always has the same value as the field 'uidd' in table2. not all the ids in table1 have same is in table2, but all the ids in table2 have an identical value in table1. I am trying to do a query witch presets to me all the records where the 'uid' has the same value 'in the other table, table2 in 'uidd' and in such case, create a DataTable witch contain this persons row from table1. how is it possible? I tried:

```
    public void ChackForActiveUsers()
    {
        string name = Request.QueryString["n"];
        string fileName = "UsersDB.accdb";
        string sql = "";
        sql += "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE uid = '(SELECT uidd FROM table2)'";
        DataTable dt = MyAdoHelper.ExecuteDataTable(fileName, sql);
        if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            output += "name - lastname - id - email - password - gender - age" + "<br/>";
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                output += "<br/><form id='mform' action='' method='get' ><input type='text' name='fname' value='" + dt.Rows[i][0] + "'/> - <input type='text' name='lastname' value ='" + dt.Rows[i][1] + "'/> -  <input type='text' name='id' value ='" + dt.Rows[i][2] + "'/> -  <input type='text' name='email' value='" + dt.Rows[i][3] + "'/> -  <input type='text' name='password' value='" + dt.Rows[i][4] + "'/> -  <input type='text' name='gender' value='" + dt.Rows[i][5] + "'/> -  <input type='text' name='age' value='" + dt.Rows[i][6] + "'/> - " + "<input type = 'text' name = 'isadmin' value = '" + dt.Rows[i][7] + "' /> <input type='submit' name='sumbm' value='update' /><input type='submit' name='sumbmm' value='ban' />";

            }
        }
        else
        {
            output = "not found";
        }
    }
```

the output i get so far is "not found" but in the database there is rows witch anware this condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use `EXISTS` and a correlated subquery searching for the ID in the other table.

```
SELECT *
       FROM table1 t1
       WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                            FROM table2 t2
                            WHERE t2.uidd = t1.uid);
```

Another option, which is closer to you syntax is using `IN`. But that's potentially slower when `table2` is large.

```
SELECT *
       FROM table1 t1
       WHERE t1.uid IN (SELECT t2.uuid
                               FROM table2 t2);
```

Comment: what is t1? and t2?

Comment: @clearwebcom: [Aliases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_%28SQL%29).

Comment: No value given for one or more required parameters

Comment: this is the eror

Comment: @clearwebcom: OK, but that very unlikely comes from these queries.

Comment: sorry, my bad. a mistake from somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

This query of yours won't work in most databases, because tables usually store more than 1 row:

```
WHERE uid = '(SELECT uidd FROM table2)'
```

This `select` after `WHERE` must always gives 1 row back , in other case it will throw an error. If you want this condition to be able to handle more `uidd` you need to replace `=` with `IN`.

Comment: still not woring. output=not found

Comment: I quess that you should change this "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE uid = '(SELECT uidd FROM table2)'" to this "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE uid = (SELECT uidd FROM table2)". SQL Server reads '(SELECT uidd FROM table2)' as a string not a select.

Comment: eror: At most one record can be returned by this subquery.

Comment: It looks to me that haven't read my post... WHERE uid in (SELECT uidd FROM table2)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the '=' to 'in':

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE table1.uid in (SELECT table2.uidd FROM table2)
```

Comment: output is still not found